A question on hybrid subconvexity for individual L-functions
Sorry to disturb. I have a question need some explanations from the experts on the MO-website.
As usual, we let $L(f,s)$ be the corresponding $L$-function associated to the newform $f$ on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, of level $q$, $q\in \mathbb{N}^+$, say. It is known that, regarding the $s$-aspect subconvex bound, one has $L(f,1/2+it)\ll  q^A (|t|+1)^{1/3+\varepsilon}$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$; see, e.g, A. Good's paper. Here, based on the functional equation, one sees that $A$ can be taken as  $A=1/4+\varepsilon $; this corresponds to the convexity bound for $L(f,s)$ in the critical strip.
My question if we know a subconvex bound in $q$-aspect, whereby one can achieve a hybrid bound simultaneously in the s and q aspects? That is, whether or not the exponent $A$ here can be taken as an exponent which is less than 1/4?
If any expert knows some relevant knowledge upon this, please show some guides. Thanks in advance.
Many many thanks.

If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

There are several confusions in your post.
1. Automorphic forms for the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ have level $q=1$ by definition. You probably wanted to talk about newforms for the Hecke congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(q)$.
2. Good only treated the case of $q=1$. The bound you claim was only proved recently (with an unspecified $A>0$) by Booker-Milinovich-Ng (2009) and Aggarwal (2020).
3. It is not known that $A=1/4+\varepsilon$ is admissible in the bound you claim. One can take $A=1/4+\varepsilon$ if at the same time the exponent of $|t|+1$ is enlarged to $1/2+\varepsilon$; this is the convexity bound.
4. As far as I know, that best hybrid subconvexity bound for the family at hand is due to Wu (2022):
$$L(f,1/2+it)\ll_\varepsilon (q(|t|+1)^2)^{1/4-1/224+\varepsilon}.$$ If the nebentypus of $f$ is fixed, then $1/224$ can be improved to $25/1536$.

Thanks for clarification of my these blurs. Much obliged.  Could you give some more comments on how to understand "...if at the same time the exponent of  is enlarged to 1/2+" in you post? Thanks.

@user528074 Sorry, that was a typo. I meant that the exponent of $|t|+1$ is enlarged to $1/2+\varepsilon$. That is, the convexity bound is $L(f,1/2+it)\ll_\varepsilon(q(|t|+1)^2)^{1/4+\varepsilon}$.

Thanks for timely reply.  Great thanks. It is really illuminating to communicate with you.
